# Containers cannot resolve DNS in CentOS

Tags: docker, networking, centos, centos8

I just installed Docker on CentOS 8. Everything went fine, I’ve run the hello_world test container and the result was successful. The issue is that inside the containers I cannot resolve any DNS queries.

For example when I type ping 8.8.8.8 (on any kind of base container such as Ubuntu or CentOS) I get the correct answer but when I try running `ping google.com` I don’t get any answer, meaning that the container is unable to resolve the DNS for any URL.

I’ve also tried running a base container like this:

```
docker run busybox ping -c 1 192.203.230.10
```

and I’m getting this (correct) output:

```
[server@localhost ~]$ docker run busybox ping -c 1 192.203.230.10
PING 192.203.230.10 (192.203.230.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.203.230.10: seq=0 ttl=51 time=32.413 ms
--- 192.203.230.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 32.413/32.413/32.413 ms
```

But now trying resolving the domain google.com with the command:

```
docker run busybox nslookup google.com
```

I get this output:

```
[server@localhost ~]$ docker run busybox nslookup google.com
nslookup: write to '8.8.8.8': No route to host
nslookup: write to '8.8.4.4': No route to host
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I’m finding this problem really frustrating since I’ve not found a way to solve it. I'm attaching for completeness a `cat /etc/resolv.conf` of both the machine running Docker and the container itself

On the machine with CentOS 8:

```
[server@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Inside any Docker container:

```
bash-4.4# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Which looks like a normal and working configuration, but when I try to ping google.com (inside the containers) I get:

```
bash-4.4# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Try again
```

What new things can I try?

Comment: I would guess [this is the issue](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-8). From this source: _Disabling critical security features is not encouraged. However, the firewalld manager in CentOS 8 prevents DNS resolution within Docker containers. This tutorial contains instructions on how to disable firewalld._

Comment: Thanks a lot @halfer, looks like your solution worked! But I'm wondering why is such a brutal practice needed in order to make the DNS system work properly. Isn't there any other way to bypass/add a firewalld rule to "ignore" docker? I'm behind a firewall now, so I don't think that could be a problem for now, but in real production envs this could be a big problem. Lemme know! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I believe it is a Centos issue, rather than a Docker one. Docker can only do what the host operating system permits, and Centos is (deliberately) quite locked-down. Can you use a different OS? DNS works in containers out of the box in Ubuntu.

Comment: In answer to your question, I would imagine that a firewalld rule would be possible, yes. I don't use Centos though, so you'd have to do some further searching.

Comment: I was using Ubuntu Server 20.04 but I wanted to try CentOS, I'm a bit of a newbie to it, but I'm trying to learn, anyway I'll make some further research about this "problem" and see if I can add some rules to "unlock" the docker interface on CentOS

Comment: Great! If you get an answer (and if Stack Overflow doesn't already have a same/similar question) then please make a self-answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem seems to be adding docker as a trusted interface on firewalld using the command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
```

and then reloading firewalld with:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

After it should work correctly (remember to reboot)